# PHP regular expression again

Tags: php, regex

Is there any difference between:

```
preg_replace( '@<(script|style)[^>]*?>.*?</\\1>@si', '', $string );
```

and

```
preg_replace( '@<(script|style)[^>]*>.*</\\1>@si', '', $string );
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extra `?` will invert the greediness of the expression (they're greedy by default in php):

- `/a+b/` will match `aaab` in `aaab`
- `/a*b/` will match `aaab` in `aaab`
- `/a*?b/` will match `b` in `aaab`
- `/a+?b/` will match `ab` in `aaab`

So, in your particular example, the non-greedy expression will catch a script tag and its contents, so to speak. While the greedy version will start matching the first script tag, and grab everything (including non-script areas) up to the very last close script tag.

Don't rely on either, though:

http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html

Answer (score 3):

Yes...

Consider this example string...

```
<script>bla</script><script>hello</script>
```

- The first one will stop matching as soon as it is satisfied; it is known as an ungreedy match.

In the above example, it will only match the first `script` element.

- The second one will match everything between the first and last closing tag, perhaps consuming other *matches* inside. This is known as greedy, as it will consume as much as it can.

It will match `<script>bla</script><script>hello</script>`.

The first non greedy probably doesn't need to be there, as it will search all non  `>` anyway, and then there should not be any other characters after it anyway (between non `>` and closing `>`).

I also need to mention using something like [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) is a much better method of getting `script` and `style` elements.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;

$dom->loadHTML($string);

$scripts = $dom->getElementsByTagName('script');

$styles = $dom->getElementsByTagName('style');
```

Comment: Take a closer look, @alex: the non-greedy version (with the added `?`) is listed first; the second one is greedy.  But the analysis is spot-on.

Comment: @Alan Whoops, I must be living in reverse today. I'll edit :)